# How do I add a color written in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, database

Is it possible to add color on approve and decline, basically green for approve and red for declined? I've tried looking it up but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['approve']))
    {
        $msg = "Approved";
        $approval="Approved";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['decline']))
    {
        $msg = "Declined";
        $approval="Declined";
    }
    $reqnumber=$_POST['reqnumber'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'pcrequest');

    $sql = "UPDATE request SET approval = '$approval' WHERE reqnumber = '$reqnumber'";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
        header("refresh:1; url=messages-admin.php?msg=$msg");
    else
        var_dump(mysqli_error($con));

?>
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 1370px; margin-left: -40px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
          <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Employee Name, Account, Platform, etc." class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fetch:

```js
$output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["approval"].'</td>';
       if ($row['status']) :
          $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
       else:
          $output .= '
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                        <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
        ';
     endif;
```

I've added the HTML and PHP code, as you can see HTML is fetching data from PHP.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You do that when you *output* the data. Not when you store it in your database.

Comment: You would add colors when displaying and you're not displaying anything.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks for this!

Comment: @AbraCadaver but my html code is fetching data from that php

Comment: But you didn't show any HTML code!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Please see my edit

Comment: `$msg = "<font style='color: red;'>Declined</font>";` you can change color as you want

Comment: @dean isn't that a query error?

Comment: where is `$_POST['approve']` set? isent it its `$row["approval"]`, for $output?

Comment: @WadeBoar  `echo $msg;` and see what happens, its not an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your color in a variable and use it wherever you want to colorize

```
$color = $row["approval"] == "Approved" ? "green" : "red";
//Then use $color in any element you want to colorize
'<td style="color:' . $color . ';">' .$row["approval"] . '</td>';
```

or use that

```
'<td style="color:' . ($row["approval"] == "Approved" ? "green" : "red") . ';">' .$row["approval"] . '</td>';
```

For multiple colors, use an `array()`

```
$colors = array();
$colors["Approved"] = "green";
$colors["Declined"] = "red";
$colors["Pending"] = "blue";

<td style="color:' . $colors[$row["approval"]] . ';">' .$row["approval"] . '</td>';
```

Comment: Awesome! What if I wanted to add another color for `pending`?

Comment: Thannk you so much!

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to generate css and html.

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['approve']))
{
    $msg = "Approved";
    $approval="Approved";
    $color = "green";
}
else if(isset($_POST['decline']))
{
    $msg = "Declined";
    $approval="Declined";
    $color="red";
}
?>
$output .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["month"]."/".$row["day"]."/".$row["year"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["empname"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["position"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["platform"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["processor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["ram"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["monitor"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phone"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phonetype"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["headset"].'</td>
            <td' . 'style="color:' . $color . '"><?=$msg?>>'.$row["approval"].'</td>';
            if ($row['status']) :
            $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
            else:
            $output .= '
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                    <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color: red; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
    ';
 endif;
```

Comment: The approval row value didn't change

Comment: `else` it cant be both

Comment: @WadeBoar This should work. If you want something besides the text color to change, let me know thanks. Also, read this about sql injection. http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @PatrickLeonard This is good but for some reason it won't work, really appreciate your help tho :D